TSP. Using subtours elimination or BnB
I want to get an exact solution to the TSP. The first way is to build
integer LP model and solve this problem using the branch and bound method. The second way is to sequentially add constraints to the original model that eliminate the subtours until the problem will be solved. Can you please tell me when it is better to use the first method or the second method or combination of them? What does the choice depend on?

I'm not an expert on TSP, but the subtour elimination formulation (DFJ) is stronger than the MTZ formulation. Here is a very short proof (for ATSP): link. I believe MTZ can still be used for solving small instances.

If you are just interested in solving one or more TSPs, as opposed to developing a software tool of your own, you should take a look at Concorde, which I believe is the state of the art TSP solver.
